# Объединение таблиц в ClickHouse

Tags: база-данных, clickhouse

Две таблицы(все типы данных числовые):
**table1(a, b, c) и
table2(d, a, b, c)**

Запрос должен выдавать:

```
    table2.d, table1.a, table1.b, table1.c
 где (table2.b - 1 < table1.b < table2.b + 1) и (table2.c - 1 < table1.c < table.c + 1)
```

Пытался сделать так и многие вариации этого:

```
    SELECT table2.d, table1.a, table1.b, table1.c 
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON 
(table1.b BETWEEEN (table2.b - 1) AND (table2.b + 1)) AND (table1.c BETWEEEN (table2.c - 1) AND (table2.c + 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стоит попробовать как-то так:

```
SELECT table2.d, table1.a, table1.b, table1.c 
FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2 WHERE
  (table1.b BETWEEEN (table2.b - 1) AND (table2.b + 1)) AND
  (table1.c BETWEEEN (table2.c - 1) AND (table2.c + 1))
```